# Strange multiple assignment error in C++

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

I have multiple assignment statement in my program as shown below where `query.constraints.size()` is supposed to return `13` (`constraints` is an array and its returning its size)

```
int num,size =  query.constraints.size();
```

When I do this `size` becomes 13 as expected but `num` becomes 9790272 for some reason.

When I do them separately as below everything is ok and both of them are 13 as expected

```
int size =  query.constraints.size();

int num =  query.constraints.size();
```

Why does my multiple assignment result in a strange a strange value ?

Comment: You don't have any assignment statements at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why does my multiple assignment result in a strange a strange value ?

Because C++ has no multiple assignment<sup>1</sup>. You are declaring two variables here, but only initialise the second, not the first.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, you can do `int a, b = a = c;` but code which does this would be deemed bad by most C++ programmers except in very peculiar circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

You're not assigning multiple times, you're declaring multiple times. You need to do something like:

```
int num, size;
size = num = query.constraints.size();
```

Answer (score 2):

A mutiple assignement would looks like:

```
int num, size;
num = size = query.constraints.size();
```

But the comma operator does not do a multiple assignement.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is actually a *declaration statement*, partially with initializer. Your code is equivalent to this code:

```
int num;  // uninitialized, you're not allowed to read it

int size(query.constraints.size());  // initialized
```

---

In general, `T x = expr;` *declares* a variable `x` of type `T` and *copy-initializes* it with the value of `expr`. For fundamental types this just does what you expect. For class-types, the copy-constructor is only formally required, but in practice usually elided.

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator doesnt do what you think it does

Comment: then what is it? It can even be overloaded http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0200__Operator-Overloading/OverloadingtheCommaOperator.htm

Comment: It's just a separator in a list. Just like there's no comma operator in `printf("Hello %s", world)`.

Comment: @Gir The comma _operator_ can be overloaded.  The comma in his statement isn't a comma operator, but part of syntax, and overloading the comma operator has no effect here.

Comment: because is a part of the variable declaration?