# Why are multiple assignments in one line considered bad style?

Tags: c++, operators

In C++ you can do multiple assignment by doing this

```
x = y = z = 10;
```

Yet multiple people have told me that is a bad style and I shouldn't be using it without giving me a reason why.

Can someone please explain to me why this is considered a bad style?

Comment: Mmn.. the only bad thing I could think of is readability..

Comment: Who is everybody? I can't think of a single problem with this, of course except for readability.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on who "everyone" is?  because this a common multi-assignment technique in only about a billion lines of source code in the world today.

Comment: For those who say that it is not readable: I would argue that if you really want to assign the same value to three variables, then this is more readable than the alternatives...

Comment: Well.. by everyday I meant multiple people have told me this. And the closest thing I can find to it is this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11904333/1496443 who also says it is a bad style

Comment: @LewsTherin, right I don't there is a cons for this assignment, the only thing when using operators is that you should know about operator precedence :
http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=442

but in your case it seems that is something straight forward.

Comment: It may be considered bad style because it's a bit more taxing to read (at 2am when you're debugging to a deadline) than three simple assignments. On the other hand, one line is less than three, so it can be argued both ways.

Comment: You should just ask the next person who tell you that it's bad style, "Why?"

Comment: @Caesar: in the answer you link there is a different context. There happens an assignment to (uninitialized) `a` and an initialization of `b`, which are semantically different yet mixed in the same line.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's not inherently bad style, but you can often make the code clearer by doing just one assignment per line and letting the compiler optimizer sort things out. If you use the multiple-assignment style then sometimes it might not be clear whether `x = y = z = 10;` was intentional or whether it was a typo for something like `x = y = z + 10;`. By always limiting yourself to one assignment per statement you make it obvious when typos occur.

Comment: Interestingly, this would also be a good example use case for commenting.  A simple `// Set x, y, and z to specified value.` would immediately clear up two potential sources of confusion (whether there's a typo, and whether all three are the same by design or happy coincidence), while relying on self-commenting code makes it confusing.  ...Which, in turn, serves to prove your point. ;P

Answer (score 43):

Try it out with those definitions:

```
int x;
bool y;
int z;
x = y = z = 10;
```

And be surprised about the value of x.

Comment: Honestly no surprise at all if you know how boolean/int conversion works. And what if you are using the same types?

Comment: I agree the 'chained' assignment invites to separating declaration and initialization, making it all too easy to overlook a discrepancy between type and value. But the real nuisance is the fact that [gcc and clang have no warning option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58144656/2485966) to make you aware of an int being implicitly narrowed to a bool.

Answer (score 10):

There is no problem as long as you know they should all be the same value.

e.g.

changing

```
x = y = z = 10;
```

to

```
x = y = z = 15;
```

is very easy.

If however, they are arbitrarily the same, separate assignments convey this, and are easier to change individually for testing.

```
x = 10;
y = 10;
z = 10;
```

to

```
x = 10;
y = 15;
z = 10;
```

is better than having to break up the line.

The key is what you are telling the next programmer to look at the code (or yourself in 6 months).