# Check whether value is iterable vba

Tags: vba, excel

In many languages it is possible to check whether an object is iterable, how do I do this for VBA?

I can try:

```
Function isIterable(obj As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim iterator As Variant
    For Each iterator In obj
        Exit For
    Next
    isIterable = Err.Number = 0
End Function
```

But I wonder if there's a builtin or a better approach?

Comment: Note that while your function supports arrays, arrays should be iterated with a `For` loop, not a `For Each` (for significant performance reasons). The calling code should test that variant with `IsArray` instead.

Comment: But since he's only iterating the first item in the list to test for iterability (it's a word now!), it won't matter that much, @Mat'sMug.

Comment: @FreeMan not in *that* function - but if some code is calling this function to discover whether something can be iterated with a `For Each` loop, and the function takes an array and says "yeah sure no problem", then it seems reasonable to assume that the calling code would branch to a `For Each` loop on whatever `obj` is. And if that's an array, then it's bloody inefficient.

Comment: So, @Mat'sMug, once it's determined that the object is iterable, a further test should be made to see if it's an array, then do the looping properly, as opposed to testing "that variant with `IsArray` _instead_".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Is there a built-in function*:
**No.**

*Is there a better approach?*:

I would have done it like this:

```
Function isIterable(obj As Variant) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo isIterable_Error

    Dim iterator As Variant

    For Each iterator In obj
        isIterable = True
        Exit Function
    Next

isIterable_Error:

End Function
```

Because putting twice `=` on the same line is a bit too much.

Comment: Why the `On Error Goto 0`, isn't that automatic on exiting a function? Also, won't raising an error skip out that line anyway? I think your approach is also better in that it doesn't involve a call to `Err.Number`

Comment: @Greedo - `On Error GoTo 0` is a habit (and is a built in function from MZTools, which I use for error handling). Indeed, it will run without it as well. And raising an error would skip it, yes. As a matter of fact this line is not reachable in any case :)

Comment: Have to disagree with putting `=` twice is too much. I find it easier to think of as _is error returning an error?  Place that answer in a variable`_.  Same thinking with _Boolean = Not Boolean_ to flip TRUE to FALSE and Visible to Invisible.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I'd go with `isIterable = (Err.Number = 0)` ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yep, that's the one. So I forgot to mention the brackets. :)

Comment: @Mat's Mug Isn't  `isIterable = (Err.Number = 0)` the same as `isIterable = Err.Number = 0` since the right hand side expression is evaluated first?

Comment: @KostasK. It is. But it fixes my OCD. And since parentheses used like this in VBA essentially mean "evaluate this expression as a value", using them here helps differenciating the assignment `=` operator from the comparison `=` operator - in other languages where assignment and comparison operators are different (e.g. `=` vs `==`), I wouldn't put the parentheses.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I have just started to write quite the same answer :)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - I was sure I can find something like this in StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106210/why-are-multiple-assignments-in-one-line-considered-bad-style

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's any better than Vityata's function, but just as an alternative:

```
Function isIterable(obj As Object) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next

    isIterable = TypeName(CallByName(obj, "_NewEnum", VbGet)) = "Unknown"
    If Not isIterable Then isIterable = TypeName(CallByName(obj, "_NewEnum", VbMethod)) = "Unknown"

End Function
```

Comment: One thing this doens't handle (that OP's code does) is arrays - take a `Variant` parameter and stick `If IsArray(obj) Then isIterable = True : Exit Function` at the top and you're good to go. Also custom collection classes couldn't have a `_NewEnum` member (underscore prefix being illegal in a VBA identifier). I expose a `NewEnum` property getter (not sure the name matters as much as the `VB_UserMemId = -4` member attribute), so further checking using `"NewEnum"` for a member name would work... but not 100% reliably. The only way to *really* do this would be with some reflection API.

Comment: You can deal with the `_` e.g. `MsgBox TypeName(aCollection.[_NewEnum])`

Comment: @AlexK. Yes, that's how custom collections invoke their internal collection's enumerator... what I'm saying is that a custom collection could very well have a `Public Property Get NextItem() As IUnknown` with a member attribute `NextItem.VB_UserMemId = -4` and there, the function will have a false negative. IOW, short of using a reflection API that enables querying a member for that specific attribute value, the best solution is what the OP has.

Comment: This is absolute COM joy.  _NewEnum is the correct approach for objects.  Mind you doesn't work for Array("foo","bar","barry")

Comment: Worth a documentation link, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221354(v=vs.85).aspx