# How to get the compiler to warn that this is an invalid bool?

Tags: c++, boolean, compiler-warnings, constexpr

We just got burnt by a typo: "**constexpr bool maxDistance=10000;**"

Both gcc and clang compile this with no warning.

The real error here is that the variable shouldn't have been of type bool, but should have been an integer type instead.

**How can we ensure we get a compiler warning in future?**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

constexpr bool number = 1234;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << number + 10000 << std::endl; // prints 10001.
    return number;
}
```

The error here is that the variable is declared with the wrong type, however neither clang nor gcc give a warning.

```
gcc -Wall -std=c++14 test.cpp -lstdc++
clang -Wall -std=c++14 test.cpp -lstdc++
```

(using gcc 5.4.0 and clang 3.8.0)

Note: I've since learnt about a possible compile flag: `-Wint-in-bool-context` however this doesn't appear to be implemented in the version I'm using (5.4.0) nor in clang (3.8.0).

Is this the right way to go?

Comment: I don't think that there is a warning for `bool number = 1234;` neither in clang nor gcc.

Comment: Assigning an integer to a bool is a legal and well-defined operation, so no warning from compilers. If you want that, find a static analysis tool which supports that option

Comment: MSVC Gives a warning: "Implicit conversion … possible information loss."

Comment: @RemyLebeau: for OP's case, it is clear, that there is a mistake. No one would initialize a `bool` with an integer literal.

Answer (score 7):

You should use *direct list initialization syntax*, it prohibits narrowing:

```
constexpr bool number{1234}; // error: narrowing conversion of '1234' from 'int' to 'bool' [-Wnarrowing]
```

Comment: Why was this down-voted? It appears to work: test.cpp:3:24: error: constant expression evaluates to 1234 which cannot be narrowed to type 'bool' [-Wc++11-narrowing]
constexpr bool number {1234};

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that gcc has a flag '-Wint-in-bool-context' however this doesn't appear to be implemented in the version I'm using (5.4.0) nor in clang (3.8.0).

Is this the right way to go?

Comment: "Warn for suspicious use of integer values where boolean values are expected". I'd say that your case definitely fulfills this, so gcc should produce a warning. But it doesn't produce. Maybe you can submit this issue as an enhancement to gcc devs.