# Why is {} initialization in C++ safer than other methods?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, c++20

I watched the talk `When C++ Style Guides Contradict` by Nicolai Josuttis and stopped at this slide. I agree with most points nowadays but could someone elaborate what he means with "safer"? Does he mean Vexing-parse problems or runtime related safety? And in which ways?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRQ1xqYBKgc

[image]

Comment: For example see [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58144656/how-to-get-the-compiler-to-warn-that-this-is-an-invalid-bool/58144813)

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926

Comment: Agree, duplicate. Thanks!